# How can i extract the email id from the href link using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code from which I need to extract the email ID.

```
<div class="Serial">
<p> … </p>
<p>
<span>
<a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.com">
    Mr. XYZ
</a>
</span>
</p>
<p> … </p>
<p> … </p>
```

The above email Id's are generated from a series of random numbers. I need to iterate it many times and every time I try to get the mail id, its failing.

I am using for loop to iterate for n times and trying with the following code :

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mr.XYZ").getAttribute("href");
Assert.assertTrue(link.contains("mailto : ....")
```

It works fine for the first iteration and fails later. How can I get the mail Id's every time I run the code?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to think about it in a different way, specifically think about how it sits within the whole document. You are using `.linkText` so you are currently bound to what text is being shown.

You can change this by using a CSS selector.

In your example, we can assume that the `anchor` is *only* link within that overlying `div` with a class `Serial`. That way, you could have a CSS selector like so:

```
div.Serial > a
```

Meaning, it *doesn't matter* what `text` is has inside it.

You could go a little further and say, well, there are other links in there too so we will ensure we only get ones that have `mailto:` in them:

```
div.Serial > a[href^='mailto:']
```

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer @Arran's answer, but I think the error you were seeing was because you were missing 1 measly character.

```
By.linkText("Mr.XYZ")
```

should have been

```
By.linkText("Mr. XYZ") // note the space.
```